# Python Craps: Creating a list with sets. Unexpected types

Tags: python, list, types, set

I am fairly new to programming and now I want to create a simple craps game in Python.
However, I instantly run into a problem. I want to make a list of 12 elements and then make all of them empty sets.

```
roll = [i for i in range(12)]   
for i in roll:  
   roll[i] = {}  
print(roll)
```

Sure it works, but there is some issue. It indicates `i` in the for-loop and says unexpected types, which makes me think there is a more legitimate way of doing this, and I'd like to know why it doesn't work. I did the test to make roll a list of 12 sets in the first place by changing the function, sure it avoids the problem, but doesn't make me learn anything about this issue.

Comment: I'm not sure how you arrived at the code you've got now, but if you want a list of 12 empty sets, you want `roll = [set() for _ in range(12)]`

Comment: yeah, I noticed that the ebook I am learning from uses set(). But why can't set() be replaced with {}, are they not the same thing. If I use set() instead of {} in the for-loop the the problem goes away.

Comment: No, `{}` is a dictionary, not a set.

Comment: ok ,well than that settles it. Thank you. I though {} was for sets

Comment: Ok, one more thing.

Comment: set1 = {1, 2, 3} makes a set right?

Comment: Yes `{1,2,3}` is a set. But `{1:2, 3:4}` is a dictionary. Because the notations are similar, `{}` is ambiguous to a reader, but Python interprets it as an empty dictionary, not an empty set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- you can define an empty set in the following way: `set()`
- `{}` it is used for an empty dictionary

you can use in your example:

```
roll = [i for i in range(12)]   
for i in roll:  
   roll[i] = set()
print(roll)
```

Comment: ok, but does set1 = {1, 2, 3} make a set?? or is my book outdated

Comment: yes it is a set, but also {1:1, 2:2, 3:3} is a  dict, so they chose {} for empty dict

Answer (score 1):

```
roll = [i for i in range(12)]
```

`roll` is a list of integers, from 0 - 11 inclusive.

```
for i in roll:
```

For every integer in the list...

```
roll[i] = {}
```

Treat the current integer as an index to the list, and replace the integer at that index with a dictionary (The literal `{}` is not a set). This happens to work the way you intended because the integers in the list happen to be the same values as the indices at which they appear in the list.

The whole thing is redundant to begin with - you don't need to create 12 integers to "allocate" space for the sets later on, just create the sets in the list comprehension:

```
roll = [set() for _ in range(12)]
```

Comment: yes, I know I could just create the sets in the list comprehension. But, I wanted to do it in a unconventional way to learn why it was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a list of sets you can do:

```
[set() for i in range(12)]
```

---

In your code you're both looping through `roll` and modifying the elements.

Also `{}` makes a `dict` not a `set`.

Comment: Ah. One sec. I'll modify.